# How to change some wrong entries in udev hardwaredatabase

Tags: usb, udev

I'm German, it's been a long time since I've written in english (over 35 years). Sorry for bad style and mistakes.
Problem:
some USB devices are recognized incorrectly. For example:

```
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 1410:1410 Novatel Wireless Merlin U740 (non-Vodafone)
```

UMTS/GPRS Modem, but really it's a Merlin U740 USB 2.0 webcam. The ID ist correct.
blacklist the modul **option** makes it work, but the desciption text is always wrong
I change it in the **/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-usb-vendor-model.hwdb** and update the **/lib/udev/hwdb.bin**

```
sudo systemd-hwdb --usr update
sudo systemctl reload udev.service
```

but that didn't work.
as well this device work correct, but the description was also wrong.

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 17a0:0002 Samson Technologies Corp. Q1U dynamic microphone
```

in truth it is about an Audio Technika AT2020 USB microphone
Ist there a simple way for me to change the wrong entries in the database?

kind regards Rainer

Comment: I’m seeing that [the AT2020 is `0909:001c`](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:0909-001c). Are you certain the hardware database is incorrect? 

Comment: Ther correct ID for the Audio Technika AT2020 USB microphone was also the same ID 17a0:0002 and for the Web-Cam ID 1410:1410 the same. I want to change the Text in the hwdb. The ID's are allegedly double.

Comment: i checked the modul assignment: 

modprobe -c  | grep -i "1410.*1410"

Result: option - thats IMHO for an old PCMCIA-Modem